# Text editor that saves difference in revisions only, not complete historical copies

Tags: windows, text-editors, revision-control

I use a text editor for my *long* to do list, and wish to keep record of what items get removed off it. However, don't want to have multiple copies of the 1/4Mb file existing on storage media. Is there any text editor that will only save the changes since a base copy (I would keep this editor up 24/7, if that helps the "Which file would it use for a base copy?" question)

Would also be nice if this program was capable of facilitating a large undo/redo history.

Does a open source and/or freeware option exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think such an editor, even if it existed, would be rather in danger of losing the file, and the files could not be easily read the resulting file, so it wouldn't be a true text document.

It is not exactly a text editor, but you need a `git` or mercurial (`hg`) repository to do all these things. To track files locally there are only a few commands you would need, so it would not be that big of a learning curve.

To me a longer Undo would only be useful if it persisted across sessions, and version control gives you this too (back up to or compare changes on any previous commit.)

Sublime Text is a popular editor that supports git-tracking plug-ins.

Add `git` to your To Do list. Another few bytes won't be noticed...

Other ideas. If storage is your utmost priority you could use a google doc or Dropbox file. Make them store it and you can use their revision history.

Comment: I think control revision software stores different copies of files, not in a differential way, as the OP wants. Otherwise, I would agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Agree but according to this (Storage efficiency) it does compress and eventually save deltas when you get a bit further removed from the source. http://superuser.com/a/159338/226698

Comment: Still... for just storing a single text file, it seems overkill. However, code is also a simple text file. Assuming the OP can handle the overhead of running a `Git` repository, then it is a solution.

Comment: Yep, can't hurt to try to promote version control, and I am sure it would be useful for other things. Without knowing the platform it is hard to give recommendations, but I don't think such an editor exists? Some weird combo using `diff`?

Comment: I don't think it is such a weird or unusual request, because version control software exists. Maybe *someone somewhere* made a plugin for Notepad++ or emacs that does this...

Comment: Yes, plug in for vc in text editor would be a good way to implement this.

Comment: @beroe - My bad about the lack of platform - Fixed; Some questions, please: Much of a difference between `git` and `mercurial`? What do you mean by "...eventually save deltas when you get a bit further removed from the source"? As for you suggestion - Very interesting idea, but as [Doktoro-Reichard](http://superuser.com/users/228536) pointed out, the overhead in (for example) simply undoing a change (Ctrl-Z normally), let alone how to seamlessly tie this into file saves with current editor (I assume), may kill this idea.

Comment: P.S Not sure if you know, but you can use the `[this](link)` structure in comments P.P.S LOL RE: Another few bites.

Comment: I guess the best solution depends on your priorities, but I haven't heard of an editor that saves just differences. I will update my answer with some more thoughts. About VC tools: it is almost religious war territory. They are very similar. I think it is safe to say that git has more users and support via plug-ins, but mercurial users say it is easier. Thanks for the reminder about links. I can never remember the order of []().

Comment: Ps. About saving deltas, as far as I understand it, the repo will have full copies of your files back a certain way into history, and then it will save compressed compilations of versions, and *then* beyond that it will store diffs (what I called deltas) summarizing just the changes.